# Selecionar 2 wheres em uma consulta com mais de 1 tabela - PHP, SQL

Tags: php, sql, where

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de advocacia para registro de processos e que poderão ser compartilhados entre os usuários envolvidos.
No momento, estou precisando filtrar processos entre datas. Já consegui fazer isso onde são listados todos os processos existentes, mas agora quero filtrar as datas de processos de determinado cliente.

Por exemplo: tenho um cliente chamado **Marcelo** e quero listar todos os processos desse cliente. Agora, quero filtrar os processos desse cliente por data. Como fazer?

Abaixo tenho o código que filtra por data

```
function GetProcessoData($data_ini,$data_fim){

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM {$this->prefix}processos p";
    $query .= " INNER JOIN {$this->prefix}clientes c ON p.pro_cliente = c.cli_id";
    $query .= " INNER JOIN {$this->prefix}user u ON p.pro_remetente = u.user_id";

    $query.= " WHERE pro_data between :data_ini AND :data_fim ";

    $query .= $this->PaginacaoLinks("pro_id", $this->prefix."processos WHERE pro_data between ".$data_ini." AND ".$data_fim);

   // passando os parametros  
    $params = array(':data_ini'=>$data_ini, ':data_fim'=>$data_fim);

    // executando a SQL
    $this->ExecuteSQL($query,$params);

    $this->GetListaAll();
}
```

Comment: André, pelo que entendi, basta adicionar mais uma condição no seu where, filtrando a tabela de cliente pelo campo que armazena o nome do mesmo, sua função teria que receber um terceiro argumento, sendo nome do cliente.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde,
Eu faria algo do tipo:

```
function GetProcessoData($data_ini,$data_fim,$nome='%'){

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM {$this->prefix}processos p";
    $query .= " INNER JOIN {$this->prefix}clientes c ON p.pro_cliente = c.cli_id";
    $query .= " INNER JOIN {$this->prefix}user u ON p.pro_remetente = u.user_id";

    $query.= " WHERE c.nome like :nome and pro_data between :data_ini AND :data_fim ";

    $query .= $this->PaginacaoLinks("pro_id", $this->prefix."processos WHERE pro_data between ".$data_ini." AND ".$data_fim);

   // passando os parametros  
    $params = array(':nome' =>nome, ':data_ini'=>$data_ini, ':data_fim'=>$data_fim);

    // executando a SQL
    $this->ExecuteSQL($query,$params);

    $this->GetListaAll();
}
```

Pois dessa forma se não passar o parâmetro do filtro de nome ele trará todos os cliente.
Espero ter ajudado